# Is it OK to update APEX metadata tables from SQL Developer? Or make changes to Application Export file?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have a requirement to make the read-only setting of 300+ IG columns in my application to null. I am able to query the columns from apex metadata views. I am wondering if it is OK to update the underlying APEX tables directly?

Or is it Ok to update the application export file and import it back again?

Will it have any negative implications or be considered malicious?

Or Is it not recommended at all?

Comment: In the designer, you can select multiple IG columns with the shift- / ctrl-keys and then perform attribute changes on all of them at once. Note that if you select only one column that does not have the read-only-setting (e.g. hidden columns), you will not be able to set it for your whole selection.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of it. But my question is.. Is it okay to directly update in metadata tables. Or in sql export file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, and I do sometimes.  However it is very much "at your own risk".  If you get it wrong you could update data that belongs to the APEX Builder itself and stop it working.  Good luck contacting Oracle support when you do that!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't touch Oracle metadata, that would be the last option if nothing else works and I'm very desperate.

I've edited export file quite a few times (in older Apex versions) as the export used to create an invalid file. For example, closing single quote was moved into a new line and import complained about it, e.g. the second line here - see that lonely single quote?

```
p_button_redirect_url => 'javascript...tree.collapse_all(''tree124124124124');
',
p_button_execute_validations => 'Y', ...
```

So, there was nothing to do but to edit the file and move it to the end of the first line.

As the export is a pure SQL textual file, no problem in editing it. Just make sure to save the original so that you could revert to it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing the operation at the database level?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself clearly. I meant to say if the IG is inherently connected to a table/view in the database then its possible to alter the base table.

Note: The base table which is connected to an IG  is **not** the same as APEX Metadata tables which is what you asked. The APEX Metadata is the dictionary tables that comprise APEX as an application and is not user data but application data.